# Unpacking Variadic Parameter Pack of Enums

Tags: c++, templates, enums, variadic

Update: Edited to fix compilation in working example.

I want to do something like the following so the function can take in both a list of the enum class instances or a struct that holds them, but the definition of `auto myFunc2<EList<Types...>>` fails with `expected a constant not E::A`

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

enum class E {A = 0, B=1};
template<E... Types> struct tl2 {};
using my_list_2 = tl2<E::A>;

template <E ... Types>
auto myFunc2 = [] {
    std::cout << "Size: " << sizeof...(Types) << std::endl;     
};

template <template<E...> typename EList, E... Types>
auto myFunc2<EList<Types...>> = [] {
    std::cout << "Size: " << sizeof...(Types) << std::endl;     
};

int main() {
    myFunc2<E::A, E::B>();  // This call prints size of typelist
                            //Works when myFunc2<Elist<Types..>> is commented out

    //myFunc2<my_list_2>();      //This breaks      
}
```

If we convert this to general types then everything compiles and works as expected. For example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template < typename ... Types > struct tl
{
};
using my_list = tl <int, float, uint64_t>;

template <typename ... Types>
static constexpr auto myFunc2 = [] {
    std::cout << "Size: " << sizeof...(Types) << std::endl;   
};

template <template<class...> class TL, typename ... Types>
static constexpr auto myFunc2<TL<Types...>> = [] {
    std::cout << "Size: " << sizeof...(Types) << std::endl;   
};

int main() {
    myFunc2<int,uint64_t,bool,uint16_t>();
    myFunc2<my_list>();                    
}
```

What is going on here? Is there a limitation in how enum classes can be handled as templates?

Comment: Err whoops. I edited the first example (which does not compile) to reconstruct the second from memory within the post itself and likely made a mistake. I'll just add a version that does compile now: https://godbolt.org/z/q1d8qvnc8

Comment: Ok,  I deleted my answer. I need to rethink it I noticed.

Comment: In second case, you have partial specialization, whereas in first case, you have redeclaration with different kind, which is forbidden. Example might be simplified to `template <typename> int ko = 0; /* ko<int> */
template <int> int ko = 0; /* ko<42> */
`

Comment: ok duh. Thanks, that makes sense. So the main solution would be to define my own classes that could be accepted by the partial spec? This is what I ended up working with. 

```
namespace E {
   struct A {
       static const int value = 0; 
       explicit operator int() const {return value;}
   };
}
```

Comment: Or are there other ways to create named type collections/parameter packs that can be reused without changing the function signature?

Comment: [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) is a way to wrap value in type...

Comment: There are also options like `std::integer_sequence<E, E::A, E::B>`, but they are mostly useful if you can allow type deduction through function arguments, which would change the signature. For example, you'd have to write your second function as `template<E... Es> auto myFunc2(std::integer_sequence<E, Es...> const&)`. The main issue is that `my_list_2` is not a template: it will only match with a `class T` template parameter unless you leverage argument deduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True **function** templates can do this (with the usual extra helper for deducing a pack):

```
template <E ... Types>
void myFunc2() {
    std::cout << "Size: " << sizeof...(Types) << std::endl;     
}

namespace detail {
template <template<E...> typename EList, E... Types>
void myFunc2(EList<Types...>>) {
    std::cout << "Size: " << sizeof...(Types) << std::endl;     
}
}

template <typename EList>
void myFunc2() {
    detail::myFunc2(EList());
}
```

This approach allows “one template” to accept template arguments of different **kinds** because the templates with the wrong kinds of template parameters will simply be ignored during overload resolution.